# Bash tr -s command

Tags: bash

So lets say I have several characters in an email which don't belong. I want to take them out with the tr command. For example...

```
jsmith@test1.google.com
msmith@test2.google.com
zsmith@test3.google.com
```

I want to take out all the `test[123].` so I am using the command `tr -s 'test[123].' < email > mail`. That is one way I have tried but the two or three I have attempted all do not work as intended. The output I am trying to get to is ...

```
jsmith@google.com
msmith@google.com
zsmith@google.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sed.

```
$ sed 's/@test[1-3]\./@/' file
jsmith@google.com
msmith@google.com
zsmith@google.com
```

`[1-3]` matches all the characters which falls within the range `1` to `3` (1,2,3). Add in-place edit `-i` parameter to save the changes made.

Comment: `-i` if you want inplace :)

Comment: Yeah I know but I am working with replacing things with tr -s at the moment. I have also tried `tr -s "test[123]." "" < email > mail` but I must have some input in the string

Comment: did you want only a `tr` solution? What's wrong with sed?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with sed I was just focusing on tr at the moment thats all